# How to split array based on length and removing first item and adding new item to the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

I want it to split as below using JavaScript:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,8,9]]
```

Comment: `const f = (a, n) => Array.from({ length: a.length - n + 1 }, (_, i) => a.slice(i, i + n)); console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const len = 5;

const result = [...Array(arr.length - len + 1)].map((_, i) => arr.slice(i, len + i));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using multiple slices.

```js
const getSlices = (arr, len) => {
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length - len; i++){
    res.push(arr.slice(i, i + len));
  }
  return res;
};
console.log(getSlices([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const split = (arr, l) => arr.reduce((res, el, i) => {
  const slice = arr.slice(i, i + l);
  if(slice.length == l) res.push(slice);
  return res;
}, []);
console.log(split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function mySplit(arr, n) {
    let result = [];
    for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-n; i++) {
        result.push(arr.slice(i, i+n));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log( mySplit(arr, 5) );
```